# R data.table using key with ! (not) effciency

Tags: r, data.table, key

I'm betting there is a simple answer to this, but is there a better way to use an R data.table key when you want the values that are NOT equal to a specific value?

In the code example below I want the values not equal to 205 and you can see that using `!` takes 3x as long even though they return the same number of rows. In this simple example you could set it equal to 100 or do a `fsetdiff()` or something, but imagine a very large table with a lot of values for ID.

```
N = 2e7L
DT = data.table(id = sample(c(100L, 205L), N, TRUE),
   loan_age = sample(0:500, N, TRUE),
   val = runif(N))

setkey(DT, id)
system.time(DT[.(205L)])  #0.108
system.time(DT[!.(205L)]) #0.396
```

Comment: Using `DT[DT[, .I[id != 205L]]]` gets me less thatn the time taken for .(205L)` and that is without the `setkey` as well

Comment: Wow, that is not syntax I would have considered! I'm seeing 0.247 for the time on that (with or without setkey). I'm still a little surprised that there isn't a way to use the key to get the time closer to the 0.108, but this is definitely an improvement (and probably the best?). If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: in your system.time, you haven't considered the time for `setkey`.  Use that along and then you will find that this is more faster

Comment: A silly workaround would be... join on id 205, then omit rows, if any: `system.time({w <- DT[.(205L), which=TRUE]; if (length(w)) DT[w] else DT})`.